# Difference between geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) and geometry(Geometry,4326)

Tags: postgis

I had imported a shapefile to PostGIS which has a column data type of `geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)`.

I have used the following SQL statement before to find a point in the polygon of given column.

```
select precinctso
from public."precinct" b
where ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText(concat('POINT(',103.84263486000195,' ',1.2739257004756506,')'),4326),b.geom::GEOMETRY)
limit 1;
```

I have tried using ST_Contains:

```
select precinctso
from public."precinct" b
where ST_Contains(b.geom, ST_GeomFromText(concat('POINT(',103.84263486000195,' ',1.2739257004756506,')'), 4326))
limit 1;
```

But both statements return empty.

These statements have been used for a similar query where the data type of the column has been `geometry(Geometry,4326)`.

I want to know whether the Geometry type MultiPolygon is any different when using `ST_Within` or `ST_Contains`.

Comment: MultiPolygon is just a constrained Geometry (prevents inserting any other kind of geometries into the table). Are you sure that you really have polygons around your point? Select some as a sample with `ST_AsEWKT(b.geom)`.

Comment: The precision of value 103.84263486000195, even in degrees, goes to atomic level. Coordinates are certainly not that accurate, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with them.

Comment: @user30184, 
if i tried suggested ST_AsEWKT, I get results such as the following:
SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((103.843910169457 1.28040143692451,103.843949875758 1.2803774168269,...

I have tried reducing lat, lon to 10 decimal places but still am not empty result.

Comment: Ok, multipolygons are at least in EPSG:4326 and in about the same place on Earth. We do not still know if your point is inside any of them. Have you compared for example with QGIS? Here is an example with inline geometries to prove that it is possible to get "true" as an answer: `select ST_Within( 
ST_GeomFromText(concat('POINT(',103.84263486000195,' ',1.2739257004756506,')'), 4326),
ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON ((( 102 3, 107 3, 103 -1, 102 3 )))',4326))`.